# Avoid duplicate data when using asp:control to insert

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET code, I use it to insert and view my data from a *.mdb file.
When I reload the browser reload, it insert the same old data.

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        DataKeyNames="user_id" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" Height="50px" 
        Width="125px" DefaultMode="Insert">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="user_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="user_name" 
                SortExpression="user_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_pass" HeaderText="user_pass" 
                SortExpression="user_pass" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_email" HeaderText="user_email" 
                SortExpression="user_email" />
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>

    <div ID="Div1" runat="server"></div>


    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/esn.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [user]"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [user] ([user_name], [user_pass], [user_email]) VALUES (@user_name, @user_pass, @user_email)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="user_name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="user_pass" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="user_email" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>





    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="user_id" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_id" HeaderText="user_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="user_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_name" HeaderText="user_name" 
                SortExpression="user_name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_pass" HeaderText="user_pass" 
                SortExpression="user_pass" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="user_email" HeaderText="user_email" 
                SortExpression="user_email" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think sendig user to a success insert page is an option!

Try look here:

[detect duplicate insert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1670519/735864)

or here:

[ASP.Net - Prevent Duplicate(Double) Inserts when Page is refreshed](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net---Prevent-DuplicateDouble-Inserts-when-Page-is-refreshed.aspx)

[How to Prevent Duplicate Record Insertion on Refresh Click in Browser in ASP.Net ?](http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/174-How-to-Prevent-Duplicate-Record-Insertion-on-Referesh-Click-in-Browser-in-ASP-Net--.aspx)

Here a Microsoft article:

[Trap the Browser Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379557%28VS.80%29.aspx#bedrockas_topic2)

Answer (score 0):

use viewstate or session to store a flag "hasSaved". when the page loads for the first time :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        ViewState["hasSaved"] = false;
}
```

and change the value of "hasSaved" to true when the the data is saved note that save the value if "hasSaved" is false 
See the full code here
[Avoid Repeated insertion due to page refresh](http://dotnetready4u.blogspot.com/2015/01/avoid-repaeted-insertion-on-page-refresh.html)